# Selenium+Python. Repeating parse operations on next page not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

So what I am trying to accomplish is to use Beautiful Soup to parse and pull information off a page, and then use Selenium to navigate to the next page, repeat this operation, until there is no next page. Here is the relevant code snippet I am having an issue with

```
while True:
    try:
        for content in cards.find_all('div',{'class':'el-card-visual'}): 
            print (content.find('img')['alt'])
            print (content.find('a')['href']) 
        elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.is-next')
        elm.click()
        URL = driver.current_url 
        driver.get(URL)
        HTML = driver.page_source
        cards = BeautifulSoup(HTML,'lxml') 
    except:
        break
```

When I try and run this, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testpull.py", line 18, in <module>
elm.click()
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 72, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 461, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:  Element is not clickable at point (172, 612). Other element would receive the click: <p class="cc_message">...</p>
(Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431  (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64)
```

I tried running it without the last bit in the try statment (Everything after the elm.click()), but it kept on looping and printing back the content from the first page over and over.

Any ideas on what would be the best solution for this issue?

Comment: Does `URL` changes after clicking `Next` button?

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with the code a bit more on my own last night, and found I had a little bit too much excess at the end there. All I needed was simply:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.is-next')
elm.click()
HTML = driver.page_source
cards = BeautifulSoup(HTML,'lxml')
```

And nothing else.